# Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module not supported : file-url

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'm getting this strange error:

```
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /home/raphy/Raphy-Template/node_modules/file-url/index.js from /home/raphy/Raphy-Template/dist/src/main/main.js not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in /home/raphy/Raphy-Template/dist/src/main/main.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules
```

And I do not understand why this happens:

`node: v16.15.0` ,
`typescript": "^4.5.4` ,
`O.S: Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop`

This is `tsconfig.json` :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types"],
    "target": "es2021",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["es2021"],
    "outDir": "dist",
    //"jsx": "react",
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@sections/*": ["app/sections/*"],
      "@app/*": ["app/*"]
    },
    "strict": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noImplicitThis": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "allowJs": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": [
    "src/index.js",
    "dist",
  ]
}
```

And  in `main.ts` I import `file-url` in this way:

```
import fileUrl from 'file-url'
```

Where I'm already importing many other packages in the same way without any problems:
For example: `import validUrl from 'valid-url';`
does not give any error

But in the compiled file `/dist/src/main.js` : I see :

```
const file_url_1 = __importDefault(require("file-url"));
```

How to solve the problem?

Comment: Have you tried deleting package-lock.json and your node_modules folder and afterwards reinstall all dependencies?

Comment: Do you use `npm-force-resolutions`?

Comment: @r3dst0rm Thank you for helping. I deleted package-lock.json and node_modules folder. Then I re-installed all dependencies, but the problem persists. With `npm-forse-resolutions`: npx npm-force-resolutions
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './package-lock.json'

Comment: That's unfortunate, I was running in a similar issue - the problem was, that the library npm-force-resolutions was used, which corrupted the package-lock file, hence my questions.

Comment: For reference: https://github.com/rogeriochaves/npm-force-resolutions/issues/57

Comment: Thank you @r3dst0rm. I solved for now just downgrading `file-url` module to the previous version. The problem in a nutshell is the following: https://github.com/sindresorhus/file-url/issues/13

Comment: thanks for keeping me in the loop. So the problem is related to the installed TypeScript version.